# CGI script error java RMI

Tags: java, webserver, cgi, rmi

Im trying to set up a cgi script for my RMI webserver, but it is giving me an HTTP 500 all the time.

My CGI script look like this.

```
# This class will support a QUERY_STRING of the form "forward=<port>"
# with a REQUEST_METHOD "POST".  The body of the request will be
# forwarded (as another POST request) to the server listening on the
# specified port (must be >= 1024).  The response from this forwarded
# request will be the response to the original request.
#
# CONFIGURATION:
#
# Fill in correct absolute path to Java interpreter below.  For example,
# the "PATH=" line might be changed to the follow if the JDK is installed
# at the path "/home/peter/java":
#
# PATH=/home/peter/java/bin:$PATH
#
PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin:$PATH
exec java \
        -DAUTH_TYPE="$AUTH_TYPE" \
        -DCONTENT_LENGTH="$CONTENT_LENGTH" \
        -DCONTENT_TYPE="$CONTENT_TYPE" \
        -DGATEWAY_INTERFACE="$GATEWAY_INTERFACE" \
        -DHTTP_ACCEPT="$HTTP_ACCEPT" \
        -DPATH_INFO="$PATH_INFO" \
        -DPATH_TRANSLATED="$PATH_TRANSLATED" \
        -DQUERY_STRING="$QUERY_STRING" \
        -DREMOTE_ADDR="$REMOTE_ADDR" \
        -DREMOTE_HOST="$REMOTE_HOST" \
        -DREMOTE_IDENT="$REMOTE_IDENT" \
        -DREMOTE_USER="$REMOTE_USER" \
        -DREQUEST_METHOD="$REQUEST_METHOD" \
        -DSCRIPT_NAME="$SCRIPT_NAME" \
        -DSERVER_NAME="$SERVER_NAME" \
        -DSERVER_PORT="$SERVER_PORT" \
        -DSERVER_PROTOCOL="$SERVER_PROTOCOL" \
        -DSERVER_SOFTWARE="$SERVER_SOFTWARE" \
        sun.rmi.transport.proxy.CGIHandler
```

In my access.log it says:

```
"POST /cgi-bin/java-rmi.cgi?forward=1099 HTTP/1.1" 500 415 "-" "Java/1.7.0"
```

In my error.log it says:

```
(104)Connection reset by peer: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed
```

I am using `RMISocketFactory.setSocketFactory(new sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIHttpToCGISocketFactory());` to force Http-to-cgi.

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong..

I have put my java-rmi.cgi file in /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

Am i suppose to add something else to the script?

The java error i get is:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
    java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed
```

**EDIT:** Visiting my cgi script as a website it give me(maybe you can't do that):

```
Java RMI Client Error

invalid command.
```

I traced this into the CGICommandHandler.java and it returns invalid command when the handler is null.

This is the debug output when i run bash -x:

```
+ PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
+ exec java -DAUTH_TYPE= -DCONTENT_LENGTH= -DCONTENT_TYPE= -DGATEWAY_INTERFACE= -DHTTP_ACCEPT= -DPATH_INFO= -DPATH_TRANSLATED= -DQUERY_STRING= -DREM                     OTE_ADDR= -DREMOTE_HOST= -DREMOTE_IDENT= -DREMOTE_USER= -DREQUEST_METHOD= -DSCRIPT_NAME= -DSERVER_NAME= -DSERVER_PORT= -DSERVER_PROTOCOL= -DSERVER_S                     OFTWARE= sun.rmi.transport.proxy.CGIHandler
Status: 400 Bad Request: invalid command.
Content-type: text/html

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Java RMI Client Error</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Java RMI Client Error</H1>

invalid command.
</BODY></HTML>
```

And if i echo out my cgi i file i get this:

```
AUTH_TYPE= 
CONTENT_LENGTH= 
CONTENT_TYPE= 
GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1 HTTP_ACCEPT=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 PATH_INFO= 
PATH_TRANSLATED= 
QUERY_STRING= 
REMOTE_ADDR=xx.xxx.x.xx 
REMOTE_HOST= 
REMOTE_IDENT=
REMOTE_IDENT REMOTE_USER= 
REQUEST_METHOD=GET SCRIPT_NAME=/cgi-bin/java-rmi.cgi.sh 
SERVER_NAME=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
SERVER_PORT=80 SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1 
SERVER_SOFTWARE=Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Status: 400 Bad Request: invalid command. Content-type: text/html
```

As you can see my many strings are empty...

**EDIT 2:** Now my acess log brings me this:

```
"POST http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/cgi-bin/java-rmi.cgi?forward=1099 HTTP/1.1" 500 415 "-" "Java/1.7.0"
```

Still HTTP 500, my error log gives my the same as before..

**EDIT 3:**

I now tried to implement the servlet of java-rmi.cgi and it's giving me errors.

My http.conf lookes like this:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so

<Location /cgi-bin/java-rmi.cgi>
ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/rmi/ServletHandler
</Location>
```

What should be the port and adress? In the guide it says localhost:8009(https://forums.oracle.com/message/4804030).

This is where i've placed ServletHandler.class:

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/rmi/WEB_INF/classes
```

My web.xml(inside WEB_INF) looks like this:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>ServletHandler</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>ServletHandler</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ServletHandler</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/ServletHandler</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I've installed tomcat 7 properly.

My access log gives me the same but my error log now gives me(with localhost:8009 set in httpd.conf):

```
[Fri Nov 15 08:16:26 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Invalid method in request \x124\x01\xb2\x02\x02
[Fri Nov 15 08:16:26 2013] [error] ajp_check_msg_header() got bad signature 3c21
[Fri Nov 15 08:16:26 2013] [error] ajp_ilink_receive() received bad header
[Fri Nov 15 08:16:26 2013] [error] ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
[Fri Nov 15 08:16:26 2013] [error] (120007)APR does not understand this error code: proxy: read response failed from (null) (localhost)
```

Error log when setting my global ip and port 80 in http.conf:

```
[Fri Nov 15 08:13:26 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Invalid method in request \x124\x01\xb2\x02\x02
[Fri Nov 15 08:13:26 2013] [error] ajp_check_msg_header() got bad signature 3c21
[Fri Nov 15 08:13:26 2013] [error] ajp_ilink_receive() received bad header
[Fri Nov 15 08:13:26 2013] [error] ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
[Fri Nov 15 08:13:26 2013] [error] (120007)APR does not understand this error code: proxy: read response failed from (null) (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
```

EDIT 4:

Now it lookes like this:

web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletHandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>rmiservlethandler.ServletHandler</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletHandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ServletHandler</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

httpd.conf:

```
 LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_ajp_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so

    <Location /cgi-bin/java-rmi.cgi>
    ProxyPass ajp://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8009/rmi/ServletHandler
    </Location>
```

I tried localhost:8009 but that gives me error, entering my servers global adress makes my webserver to halt, HTTP 503. Stop responding.

My error log for localhost:

```
[Fri Nov 15 12:20:53 2013] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: AJP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 (localhost) failed
[Fri Nov 15 12:20:53 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Fri Nov 15 12:20:53 2013] [error] proxy: AJP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

error log for global ip:

```
[Fri Nov 15 12:37:23 2013] [error] (110)Connection timed out: proxy: AJP: attempt to connect to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8009 (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx) failed
[Fri Nov 15 12:37:23 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
[Fri Nov 15 12:37:23 2013] [error] proxy: AJP: failed to make connection to backend: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Tomcatlog gives me this:

```
My tomcatlog gives me this: 
xx.xxx.x.xx - - [15/Nov/2013:13:32:14 +0000] "POST /rmi/ServletHandler?forward=1099 HTTP/1.1" 404 987
```

EDIT 5.

Didn't work, i get 404 for /rmi/ServletHandler.

Here is my httpd.conf(taking away .cgi):

`<Location /cgi-bin/java-rmi> ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/rmi/ServletHandler </Location>`

This is web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app> <servlet> 
<servlet-name>ServletHandler</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>rmiservlethandler.ServletHandler</servlet-class> 
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> </servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>ServletHandler</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>/ServletHandler</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

The folder setup is now:

/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/rmi/WEB_INF.

WEB_INF contains web.xml and classes/rmiservlethandler/ where rmiservlethandler is where all my class files are(package structure).

Why isn't this working?

My /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ is empty that is should be right?

My servlet dosen't run...
Thanks!

Comment: java-rmi.cgi is already provided, isn't it You don't have to write your own. But you should be using the servlet version.

Comment: Allright, dosen't the servlet use the same file?  I mean that the servlet won't solve it if the problem is the http-to-cgi? But i Will try implement servlet instead. Otherwise it is something with my Apache config.

Comment: No the Servlet doesn't use the same file, it is all done inside the Servlet. It's distributed with the JDK samples.

Comment: Now i have implemented the servlet. This is what i have done(Se edit 3)

Comment: The AJP port is whatever port the Tomcat AJP connector is listening on. The normative reference is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-protocol5.html). Your `ServletHandler` class name is wrong. It's in the `rmiservlethandler` package.

Comment: Allright so port 8009 it is, but i don't where i should change to rmiservlethandler? Is my http.conf right? Should something be placed in my sites-avalible?

Comment: Okey, my set up now(EDIT 4).

Comment: Allright now i'm getting 404 on rmi/ServletHandler, so tomcat is working atleast. Can't figure it out..

Comment: Check the normative reference! You need to get rid of then .cgi from the Location.

Comment: Didn't work, i get 404 for /rmi/ServletHandler.

Here is my httpd.conf(taking away .cgi):
<Location /cgi-bin/java-rmi>
ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/rmi/ServletHandler
</Location>

This is web.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>ServletHandler</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>rmiservlethandler.ServletHandler</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ServletHandler</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/ServletHandler</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved it!**

My folder setup were correct(except WEB-INF instead of WEB_INF), the problem was that my localhost adress in ServletHandler wasn't resolved properly(my localhost name wasn't localhost..).
Other things like WEB_INF should be WEB-INF...

Following this gave my exceptions in tomcat catalina.out and local host log files.
So if you think your servlet is running properly, look there for exceptions. I modified my ServletHandler with logs so i could se everything that was going on.

This is what my POST from the client looks now inside tomcat logs:

```
xx.xxx.x.xx - - [18/Nov/2013:13:17:23 +0000] "POST /rmi/ServletHandler?forward=1099 HTTP/1.1" 200 1
```

My http.conf:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so

<Location /cgi-bin/java-rmi.cgi>
ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/rmi/ServletHandler
</Location>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>ServletHandler</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.foo.bl.server.ServletHandler</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ServletHandler</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/ServletHandler</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Folder structure:

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/rmi/WEB-INF/classes/
```

Inside classes you put the same folder structure you have in your java IDE.
Web.xml should be placed inside WEB-INF.

Any lib files needed should be placed in WEB-INF/lib.

Hope it helps someone out there!

Regards Gustav